# Calculate average pace

Tags: swift

I need to convert a decimal hour in to hh:mm:ss to display as average pace for a walking app.

I have converted the time to decimal and I have calculated the pace in to decimal however I am unsure how to convert this to time.

My timeDecimal is:

```
let timeDecimal:Double = (hourSource + (minuteSource / 60) + (secondSource / 3600)) / distanceSource
```

which gives me something like 0.4375

```
0 = 0
.4375 * 60 = 26.25
.25 = * 60 = 15
```

I know the time should be 00:26:15 but not sure the formula to achieve this without splitting up the result and performing the multiplication multiple times.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hey, just out of curiosity, how did you calculate your average pace? PS I have written a small function to convert the decimal into your format

Answer (score 3):

```
let formatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.allowedUnits = [ .Hour, .Minute, .Second ]
formatter.unitsStyle = .Positional
formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .Pad
let string = formatter.stringFromTimeInterval(0.4375 * 3600)!
```

Result: `0:26:15`.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. Anyway to format the output 00:26:15 (double 00 if no hour)?

Comment: As far as I can tell, `NSDateComponentsFormatter` doesn't offer that option. You can pad it manually, although doing so is somewhat obtuse. Example: `(string.characters.dropFirst().first! == ":" ? "0" : "") + string`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var mytime = timeDecimal * 60
var minutes = floor(mytime)
var seconds = (mytime - minutes) * 60
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func timeStringFrom(time time: Int) -> String {

    let HoursLeft = time/3600
    let MinutesLeft = (time%3600)/60
    let SecondsLeft = (((time%3600)%60)%60)

    if HoursLeft == 0 {
        return String(format:"%.2d:%.2d", MinutesLeft, SecondsLeft)
    } else {
        return String(format:"%2d:%.2d:%.2d", HoursLeft, MinutesLeft, SecondsLeft)
    }
}
```

**Note: I'll probably turn it into a generic function soon**